# Finding the lowest 8 values in an Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, syntax, sum, integer

I am complete novice who is trying to supplement online course learning, by building some rudimentary programs. I am currently trying to build a program to calculate one's golf index. In order to do this, I must first calculate the average of the lowest 8 rounds, of the golfer's last 20. Calculating the average of the last 20 rounds was easy enough. It is isolating the lowest 8 rounds from the last twenty that I cannot figure out.

Generalized, how does one calculate the sum of the lowest N values in an array?

A note for the golfers out there: for the purposes of this exercise I am imagining that the individual only plays at one course, with a par of 72. I realize that the program will not work as currently constructed if par changes.

```
var scores: Array = [98, 99, 87, 86, 88, 92, 88, 87, 84, 98, 85, 84, 80, 99, 100, 101, 94, 96, 79, 99, 92, 94, 87, 99, 80]

var lastTwentyScores = scores.suffix(20)
var total = lastTwentyScores.reduce(0, +) 
var avg = Double(total) / Double(lastTwentyScores.count)
var index = avg - 72
```

Right now, it is giving me the average of the last twenty - 72.

I know I will need to create a new variable, and change the final divisor to 8, instead of 20. I just don't know how to call the 8 lowest values from the array.

Comment: Hint: sort the array before getting the suffix (or prefix).

Comment: It will have to be done after the suffix, as the order of the array is dependent on the time the round is played, so the order has to stay the same. But thank you. Would it make sense to sort the values of lastTwentyScores, then create a prefix of 8?

Comment: Your last sentence is exactly what you need to do. I should have been clearer that I meant sorting before getting the suffix for the 8, not the 20.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider removing the golf example from the question, and just saying "How do I get the average of the nth lowest data in an array". Might help with clarity :)

Comment: I did put this (basically) in the question "Generalized, how does one calculate the sum of the lowest N values in an array?" I thought context might help make my question more clear, but I understand if the opposite happened. I will try to make questions generalized in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to sort the last 20 and take the first 8 of that sorted result. That will give you the lowest 8 of the last 20.

```
var scores: Array = [98, 99, 87, 86, 88, 92, 88, 87, 84, 98, 85, 84, 80, 99, 100, 101, 94, 96, 79, 99, 92, 94, 87, 99, 80]

var lastTwentyScores = scores.suffix(20)
var lowestEightScores = lastTwentyScores.sorted().prefix(8)
var total = lowestEightScores.reduce(0, +)
var avg = Double(total) / Double(lowestEightScores.count)
```

This gives a total of 666 and an average of 63.25.

You can simplify most of the code to just:

```
var total = scores.suffix(20).sorted().prefix(8).reduce(0, +)
```

This makes it nice and neat but having the intermediate steps can make it easier to read and certainly easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Like @HangarRash said, it's a lot easier to do this if you sort the scores first. Simply sort the array in ascending order, and fetch the first 8 elements.

```
var scores: Array = [98, 99, 87, 86, 88, 92, 88, 87, 84, 98, 85, 84, 80, 99, 100, 101, 94, 96, 79, 99, 92, 94, 87, 99, 80]


scores = scores.sorted()           //Sorts the scores (from least to greatest)


var eightLowestScores: Array = scores[...8] // Gets the first 8 elements based on their index.
```

Comment: Please review the question and comments. The need is to get the lowest 8 of the last 20 scores. And you can use `reduce` to get the total instead of using your own loop.

Comment: @HangarRash You're right, thanks. Feel free to make your own answer if you have a better method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
scores
    .suffix(20)         // last 20
    .sorted()           // sort to get the ordered slice
    .prefix(8)          // 8 lowest
    .reduce(0, +) / 8   // average
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I got there from HangarRash’s hint, but thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

[Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) provide an optimised way: [`min(count:sortedBy:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/MinMax.md)

```
import Algorithms

let scores = [98, 99, 87, 86, 88, 92, 88, 87, 84, 98, 85, 84, 80, 99, 100, 101, 94, 96, 79, 99, 92, 94, 87, 99, 80]
let lowestEight = scores.suffix(20).min(count: 8, sortedBy: <)
let average = lowestEight.reduce(0.0) { $0 + Double($1) / Double(lowestEight.count) }
print(average - 72)
```